# Django url routing with flatpages

Tags: django, django-urls, django-flatpages

I'm having real troubles understanding how url routing works in django when using flatpages and was hoping someone could take a look at my code and explain what I'm doing wrong.

Also, it would be really helpful to have some advice on debugging this - ideally, when a request is successfully resolved, I'd like to see how django reaches that resolution.  At the moment i only see the url patterns attempted when i get a 404.

Thanks in advance,

In settings.py I have - APPEND_SLASH = True

I have the following url structure, in brackets I have indicated what I think my reg ex *should* be doing..

```
#urls.py

url(r'^$', home), # (match / and nothing else)
url(r'^fa/$', home), # (match /fa and nothing else)
url(r'^en/$', en_home), # (match /en and nothing else)

url(r'^fa', include('ir_site.urls')), # (match any path like fa/*/) 
url(r'^en', include('en_site.urls')), # (match any path like en/*/)

#in ir_site.urls
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'contact/$', views.static_contact) # (match fa/contact)
)
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.flatpages.views', 
    (r'^(?P<url>.*/)$', 'flatpage'), # (match any fa/*/ not resolved or 404)
)

#in en_site.urls
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'contact/$', views.static_contact) # (match en/contact)
)
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.flatpages.views', 
    (r'^(?P<url>.*/)$', 'flatpage'), # (match any en/*/ not resolved or 404)
)
```

I have the following flat pages

```
/en/test/
/fa/test/
/test/
/en/test2
```

Results of testing:

```
/ - Fine
/en - Fine
/fa - Fine
/test - Fine    
/fa/test - Fine
/en/test - Extra / is appended results in 404
/en/test2 - Fine, but uses the flatpages template in the ir_site app
/en/contact - Fine
/fa/contact - Fine
```

I have a feeling the problem is with (r'^fa') and (r'^en') not working correctly with the catch all for flatpages but I don't know how to *see* why that is as I lack any kind of debug skills at this stage.

Help much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by removing any reference to flatpages in urls.py and just using the middleware, I found all problems disappeared and everything started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Change your urls.py to the following for the includes. You need to have a trailing / on the url.

```
url(r'^fa/', include('ir_site.urls')),
url(r'^en/', include('en_site.urls')),
```

Also for your url parameter, I think you'd be better off using a `+` rather than an `*` since it will require 1 or more characters whereas the * is 0 or more.

Finally, in ir_site.urls and en_site.urls you should lead the contact with with an `^` so it will only match when contact is the first part of the url (after en/ or fa/).

Edit:
Change the flatpage url pattern. Currently using the `.` will match a `/`. The example I've giving will match any alphanumeric character long with hyphens.

```
(r'^(?P<url>[-\w]+)/$', 'flatpage'),
```

Comment: Hmm, have tried this but it changes nothing.  The problem is with the flatpages urls not the contact url's which always resolved ok.  Also, it seems en/test does not resolve as django resolves it to /en/test// (double slash) which is a 404

Comment: Sorry, but not sure why changing '.*' to '[-\w]+' would help? (I tried it and it didn't..)  The problem is definitely with includes though as when i comment out 'r'^fa/' and 'r'^en/' the flat pages still resolve.  The problem is the catchall pattern in ir_site.urls and en_site.urls